# How to iterate over array with multiple values

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, for-loop, push

I'm trying to populate a select box from an array. I need the value to be different from the text.

So far, this code is working, as I get the correct values:

```
var myArray = [];
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_labelTider > div').each(function () {
    myArray.push({
        content: $(this).find('th').text(),
        id: $(this).attr('id')
    });
});
console.log(myArray);
```

However, I have not been able to figure out or find via Google, how to iterate trough these and get the values.

```
for(arr = 0; arr < myArray.length; arr++) {

    jQuery('<option/>', {
        value: myArray[arr],
        text: myArray[arr]
    }).appendTo('.selectLocation');
}
```

This results in `[object Object]`

Anyone able to guide me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're setting the entire object as the attribute values, not the relevant properties from that object. Try this:

```
for(arr = 0; arr < myArray.length; arr++){
  jQuery('<option/>', {
    value: myArray[arr].content,
    text: myArray[arr].id
  }).appendTo('.selectLocation');
}
```

Note that you can make the code much more succint by using `map()` to create an array containing the HTML string and then `join()` it all together as you append:

```
var html = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_labelTider > div').map(function() {
  return `<option value="${this.id}">${$(this).find('th').text()}</option>`;
}).get();
$('.selectLocation').append(html.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`value: myArray[arr].content` for value 
and
 `value: myArray[arr].id`  because your `myArray` is array of object.

```
for(arr = 0; arr < myArray.length; arr++){

        jQuery('<option/>', {
        value: myArray[arr].content,
        text: myArray[arr].id
            }).appendTo('.selectLocation');
    }
```